# make the function code reusable angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a 2 controllers and I have a same function that is declared inside the two controllers.

My function is:

```
 $scope.users = function() {
        alert("user")    
 };
```

My question is how can I declared it once. Repeatable code is not good ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `factory, services, providers and values`. `https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a factory like

```
app.factory('ShowAlertFactory', function(){
    return {
      showAlertMessage : function(){
        alert("user");
      }
    }
});
```

Now you can inject this ShowAlertFactory in any controller and call `ShowAlertFactory.showAlertMessage();`

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your common functions in a service or factory and then inject it into your controllers

**Factory Code**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.factory('alertFactory', function() {
    return {
       alertMessage : function(){
           alert("user");
   }
}
```

To inject the factory, try this

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['alertFactory', function(alertFactory) {
});
```

**Reference:**

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers

Answer (score 0):

```
(angular.module('myApp', [])
    .factory('alertFactory', alertFactory);
    .controller('alertCtrl', alertCtrl);

function alertFactory () {
    return {
        alertMessage : function(){
        alert("user");
    }
}

alertCtrl.$inject = ['alertFactory'];
function alertCtrl(alertFactory){
    alertFactory.alertMessage();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding this code to a factory will suffice if you are only duplicating the js. However if you are also duplicating html, a better way to handle this situation is with a directive.

Try identifying if the html is also being duplicated, and utilize directives if that is the case.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        template: "html common to both controllers",
        link: function() {
            // js common to both controllers
        }
    }
}
```